# Base URL Discrepancy Between Localhost and Deployed - create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, create-react-app

I am building a web application from the ASP.Net Core React template, whose "ClientApp" React portion appears to be a 'create-react-app' project. When I deploy the app to IIS, it gets hosted in a subfolder from the root, i.e. `http://myserver.com/SubApp`. Because of this, I have changed the "homepage" value in package.json to `http://myserver.com/SubApp`.

What I am now experiencing is that when I am making `fetch` calls in my javascript code locally, if I use `fetch('/myendpoint')`, the the url requested locally is `https://localhost:44315/myendpoint` (which works), but when deployed, this url becomes `http://myserver.com/myendpoint`, which does not work.

Conversely, when I make the endpont `fetch('myendpoint')` (no leading slash), the server requests the correct URL `http://myserver.com/SubApp/myendpoint` but localhost fetches the incorrect URL, `https://localhost:44315/SubApp/myendpoint`.

I understand that the leading slash makes the request from the root, but the root appears to be different in localhost vs. on the server.

For local debugging purposes, I tried setting a proxy in package.json to `https://localhost:44315` so that hopefully `fetch('myendpoint')` (no leading slash) would work in my local environment, but when I try this, chrome prompts me to sign in repeatedly without ever successfully making the request.

I feel like I am almost there, but I must be missing something. How can I configure my package.json (or other project configuration) to make the fetch commands succeed on both localhost and my server, without doing something hacky like checking the URL in the javascript code before every fetch?

Comment: I made a sample code with the `template react` in `Visual Studio` and it worked and I got the publisher and I tested it in the local web server and it worked.

Comment: Try "homepage": "." in package.json
For reference: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#serving-the-same-build-from-different-paths

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is [Proxying API Requests in Development](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development).

It easily allows you to call any endpoint in development and forward it to your backend or other location without CORS issues or your problem of mismatched endpoints.

You will have to use the manual configuration option, since the default `proxy` setup only helps with host/port forwarding.

Install `http-proxy-middleware` as a dev dependency:

```sh
$ npm -i http-proxy-middleware --save-dev
```

Following the guide linked above, you can use this configuration:

```js
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(
    '/SubApp/*',
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: 'localhost://44315', // or anything else, point to your dev backend
      pathRewrite: {
          '^/SubApp': '/', // remove base path
      },
    })
  );
};
```

You can then fetch with the `/SubApp` part in the request which will be removed in developement. You can use other configurations to achieve this, this is one example.

Comment: As soon as I installed http-proxy-middleware and then added this setupProxy.js file, I am receiving this error when I try to run locally...

Comment: An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (One or more errors occurred. (The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the create-react-app server was listening for requests. The error output was: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! myapp._0@0.1.0 start: `rimraf ./build && react-scripts start`

npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the myapp._0@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

Comment: Forgot to include this, you need to add `http-proxy-middleware` as a dev dependency. `npm i http-proxy-middleware --save-dev`

Comment: Hmmm... I am still getting the same error after running the install with --save-dev.

Comment: OK I could reproduce it. You need to add the target key. I'll update my answer

Comment: at this point it is not crashing like it was before, but it is simply not fetching the correct URL still. I am using the updated answer, and my homepage value in package.json is still my deploy URL (http://myserver.com/SubApp), and when I use ```fetch('endpoint')``` it is still making a get request to the url ```http://myserver.com/SubApp/endpoint``` instead of ```http://myserver.com/endpoint```

Comment: Is there any other useful information I can provide you?

Comment: Ok I have got it working, I had to get rid of the homepage value in my package.json, and then add '/SubApp' in front of all of my route's URLs.

Comment: Great! You can still use homepage, it doesn't interfere.

Comment: Actually in order to get your solution to work, I had to change my routes, for example make <Route exact path="/page1"> into  <Route exact path="/SubApp/page1">. Without homepage specified in package.json, this route can be navigated to, but if I _do_ specify homepage then it navigates me to https://localhost:44315/SubApp/SubApp/page1 instead of https://localhost:44315/SubApp/page1

Comment: No, you should set the `basename` of `<BrowserRouter>` to fix the react router issue. You can still leave homepage

Answer (score 1):

I had this same experience as well and found that setting the homepage value in the package.json is a dead end. What you want to do is make use of the [PUBLIC_URL](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/advanced-configuration/) environment variable to set a full absolute url in your `.env` . There may be a way to use relative urls, but there were some edge cases that just made it cleaner to use an absolute URL.

When you set this environment variable you want to make use of it in the following places:

- Your Routes (if you use react router)

  - The path should be prefixed by `process.env.PUBLIC_URL`
- Your internal links should also be prefixed by the env var.

Comment: In what file should I try to change process.env.PUBLIC_URL?

Comment: Ok I have just created a new file, .env, in the root of my project. It has the line ```PUBLIC_URL=http://myhostname.com/SubApp``` in it, but when I print process.env.PUBLIC_URL from within my app, I get the exact same relative URL as when I just set the homepage value in package.json... Both just print out "/SubApp".